# No tabs when pointing Console2 to Cygwin

Tags: terminal, cygwin, console2

I'm trying to get Console2 to work with my Cygwin installation. I've configured my shell in Console2 to point to `C:\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico -`, but when I open a "new tab" it just opens a whole new Cygwin window, outside of Console2. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### What am I doing wrong?

```
C:\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico -
```

`mintty.exe` is a terminal that has it's own window.

It is not designed to run inside a window belonging to another program.

```
$ mintty --help
Usage: mintty [OPTION]... [ PROGRAM [ARG]... | - ]

Start a new terminal session running the specified program or the user's shell.
If a dash is given instead of a program, invoke the shell as a login shell.

Options:
  -c, --config FILE     Load specified config file
  -e, --exec            Treat remaining arguments as the command to execute
  -h, --hold never|start|error|always  Keep window open after command finishes
  -i, --icon FILE[,IX]  Load window icon from file, optionally with index
  -l, --log FILE|-      Log output to file or stdout
  -o, --option OPT=VAL  Override config file option with given value
  -p, --position X,Y    Open window at specified coordinates
  -s, --size COLS,ROWS  Set screen size in characters
  -t, --title TITLE     Set window title (default: the invoked command)
  -u, --utmp            Create a utmp entry
  -w, --window normal|min|max|full|hide  Set initial window state
      --class CLASS     Set window class name (default: mintty)
  -H, --help            Display help and exit
  -V, --version         Print version information and exit
```

---

#### I don't have a `cygwin.bat` in my `cygwin64\bin` dir

`cygwin.bat` is located in the base cygwin install directory, in my case `/c/cygwin` (which is also `C:\cygwin`).

```
DavidPostill@Hal /c/cygwin
$ cd /c/cygwin

DavidPostill@Hal /c/cygwin
$ ls
bin  Cygwin.bat  Cygwin.ico  Cygwin-Terminal.ico  dev  etc  home  lib  sbin  tmp  usr  var

DavidPostill@Hal /c/cygwin
$ cat cygwin.bat
@echo off

C:
chdir C:\cygwin\bin

bash --login -i
```

Comment: Well, junk. I don't have a `cygwin.bat` in my `cygwin64\bin` dir like the examples in other posts show. Any idea what I should be pointing to?

Comment: @ctote You are looking in the wrong place. Answer updated.

Comment: Very awesome! For anyone else in the future looking at this, if you don't immediately see `cygwin.bat` in your `C:\cygwin` path when setting your shell, make sure the selector in `Console2` isn't set to _only_ look for `exe` files (by default, mine was).

Comment: @ctote "when setting your shell" the shell, of course is `bash` not `cygwin.bat` ...

Comment: yep, but Console2 has the field labeled as `Shell` so, just going based on their UI